# I am trying to set value for event.dataTransfer.setData("applicaiton/pdf",value), but acrobat ignores it when i drag and drop from browser to acrobat

Tags: javascript, pdf, drag-and-drop, adobe, acrobat

So i am trying to do a drag and drop operation from my web application running on my browser to adobe acrobat Reader on my Windows OS, so for that i am trying to set the dataTransfer value for application/pdf

```
canvas.addEventListener("dragstart", (e) => {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("application/pdf", value);
});
```

but i am not able to understand what value i am suppposed to pass.

I tried different things like file, binary pdf data,etc but on dropping adobe acrobat reader it just ignores the file.